# using a single query to eliminate N+1 select issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return the last report of a given range of units. The last report will be identified by its time of creation. Therefore, the result would be a collection of last reports for a given range of units. I do not want to use a bunch of SELECT statements e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE unit_id = 9999 ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE unit_id = 9998 ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 1
...
```

I initially tried this (but already knew it wouldn't work because it will only return 1 report):

```
'SELECT reports.* FROM reports INNER JOIN units ON reports.unit_id = units.id WHERE units.account_id IS NOT NULL AND units.account_id = 4 ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 1'
```

So I am looking for some kind of solution using subqueries or derived tables, but I can't just seem to figure out how to do it properly:

```
'SELECT reports.* FROM reports
WHERE id IN 
(
  SELECT id FROM reports
  INNER JOIN units ON reports.unit_id = units.id
  ORDER BY time desc
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Any solution to do this with subqueries or derived tables?

Comment: have you explored the [HAVING](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/having.php) clause?

Comment: I think this question may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group?rq=1 as it sounds familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to do this in Postgres uses `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (unit_id) r.*
from reports r
order by unit_id, time desc;
```

This construct is specific to Postgres and databases that use its code base.  It the expression `distinct on (unit_id)` says "I want to keep only one row for each `unit_id`".  The row chosen is the first row encountered with that `unit_id` based on the `order by` clause.

EDIT:

Your original query would be, assuming that `id` increases along with the `time` field:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reports r
WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id)
             FROM reports
             GROUP BY unit_id
            );
```

You might also try this as a `not exists`:

```
select r.*
from reports r
where not exists (select 1
                  from reports r2
                  where r2.unit_id = r.unit_id and
                        r2.time > r.time
                 );
```

I thought the `distinct on` would perform well.  This last version (and maybe the previous) would really benefit from an index on `reports(unit_id, time)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a where clause like this: "SELECT DISTINCT ON (unit_id) r.* FROM reports r WHERE reports.unit_id IN (9988,9999) ORDER BY unit_id, time DESC". This gives me something like invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "reports"

Comment: @JohnMerlino I think you just failed to use the alias; `WHERE r.unit_id IN (...)`

Comment: I tried using this query, but it is running incredibly slow. After around 10 minutes, I just had to cancel the load. When I was using the SELECT statements, it took long but not nearly as long (only 7 or 8 seconds).

Comment: Any ideas why this query runs so slow?